# Not able to view the latest file from a directory in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I need to get the latest file from a directory, so using `LINQ` I got the file name and gave that file path as a link. When I click the link the file opens. But the problem happens when I click the link for the second time, after closing it. The old content is getting displayed, even though the file has been updated.

I get the file using the following piece of code:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\MyDirectory");
var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
             orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
             select f).First();`
```

Then i assign the above file with link to a label using the following code.

`label.text="<a href=\"" + "Log\\" + myFile + "\" target = '_NEW' runat='server'>Click</a>"`

Comment: How are you retrieving and viewing the file - do you have some sample code please? Are you sure it isn't being cached anywhere?

Comment: we cannot read your mind, mentioned code plz.

Comment: What do you then do with the file?

Comment: Do you write it out to the browser, for example?

Comment: _"when i click the link for the second time, after closing it. The old content is getting displayed"_ - how do you read the file, how do you display it?

Comment: Is label actually a Literal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely related to a caching "issue".

The easiest workaround is to change your url, append a time (ticks) related name-value like `"&t=654102310650"`.

That way the url will never be the same so the content will never get retrieved from the browser's cache.

Comment: You could of course use the modification date of your file as time reference.

Comment: I don't think i can use the query string because, i assign it to a label as shown in the above updated code.

Answer (score 1):

> `FileSystemInfo.Refresh` takes a snapshot of the file from the current
>   file system.
>    ....
>
> Calls must be made to Refresh
>   before attempting to get the attribute information, or the information
>   will be outdated.

[from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh.aspx)